# How to add multiple values in input one after another using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I m trying to add multiple coupon values from Chrome extension to input But my code is inserting only last values in the input. it console accurately according to cupon count but not inserting all the values in in input. I am unable to figure out whats going wrong with the code?

Here is my code:

```
function autoTest(tabId){
var res=res1=res2='';
var cuponInput='';
     var arr=['cupon','coupon','discount','promotion','code']
    $("input").each(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        var name=$(this).attr('name');
        var placeholder=$(this).attr('placeholder');  
        for (var i in arr){
            if(id !== undefined){
                res=id.search(arr[i]);
                if(res>-1){
                    cuponInput=$(this).attr("id");
                }
            }
            if(name !== undefined){
                res1=name.search(arr[i]);
                if(res1>-1){
                    cuponInput=$(this).attr("id");
                }
            }
            if(placeholder !== undefined){
                placeholder=placeholder.toLowerCase();
                res2=placeholder.search(arr[i]);
                if(res2>-1){
                    cuponInput=$(this).attr("id");
                    //alert("found");
                }
            }    
        }
    });
    // $('#'+cuponInput).val('');
    // alert($("#"+cuponInput).val());
    // $("#"+cuponInput).val('abc'); 
    //document.execCommand('insertText',false,'abc');
    if(res>-1 || res1>-1 || res2>-1){
        id=tabId;
        //alert(id);
        chrome.storage.local.get(id,function(res){
            if(typeof res[id] !== undefined){
                if(id in res){
                    var offers=res[id].voucherInfo.response;
                    $(offers.codes).each(function(index,cupon){
                        console.log(offers.codes);
                         //setTimeout(function(){
                            //console.log(i);
                            $('#'+cuponInput).val('');
                            $("#"+cuponInput).focus();
                            document.execCommand("insertText",false,cupon.meta.cmd_code[0]);
                    });  //}, 3000);     

                }
            }   
        });
    }
```

}

Comment: Your `$('#'+cuponInput).val('')` clears the value.

Comment: @wOxxOm I want to test all the coupons one by one how can i achieve them?

Comment: I guess you'll have to run each callback in setTimeout with progressively increasing timeout parameter e.g. setTimeout(cb, i*100, param1, param2)